# Solving system of equations by Jacobi's method

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I should solve this system of equations with Jacobi's method:
$$
{ \begin{cases}
2x_1&+x_2&&&&=3 \\
-x_1&+2x_2&+x_3&&&=2 \\
&-x_2&+2x_3&+x_4&&=2 \\
&&-x_3&+2x_4+x_5&&=2 \\
&&&-x_4+2x_5&&=1
\end{cases} }$$

I rewrite the equations:

$x_1=\frac12(3-x_2)$

$x_2=\frac12(2+x_1-x_3)$

$x_3=\frac12(2+x_2-x_4)$

$x_4=\frac12(2+x_3-x_5)$

$x_5=\frac12(1+x_4)$

Then considered initial values $x_1^{(0)}=3,x_2^{(0)}=3,x_3^{(0)}=3,x_4^{(0)}=3,x_5^{(0)}=3$ and substitute them in the equations and I got $x_1^{(1)}=0,x_2^{(1)}=1,x_3^{(1)}=1,x_4^{(1)}=1,x_5^{(1)}=1$ and substitute these new values in the equations again and get $$x_1^{(2)}=x_2^{(2)}=x_3^{(2)}=x_4^{(2)}=x_5^{(2)}=1$$
The final answer is correct. I realized if I consider other initial values (for example $x_i^{(0)}=5$) after two steps I get the answer. So did I solve it correctly?

Comment: $x_5^{(1)}$ should be $2$, right?

Comment: Oh you are right.

Comment: I haven't fully checked all the arithmetic, but your method is correct. It is true that changing the initial values will change the estimate that you get after two steps.

Comment: Thank you. It seems I made some mistakes I will fix them.